# Will applying for a masters in the same/similar field where I did my postgraduate diploma and a postgraduate program a problem in German Universities?

Tags: graduate-admissions, masters, application, germany

I have read that doing a master's in a similar field and then applying for the same master's elsewhere will weaken an application.
However, my case is slightly different. After doing a BSc Industrial Engineering (4 years), I have worked in startups for 3 years and then, I have done a postgraduate diploma in applied statistics (1-year) and a postgraduate executive program in data science/business analytics (11 months). They aren't full-fledged masters. I am applying for MSc Data Science or MSc Information Systems programs. I am really concerned and confused if my postgrad diploma and postgrad program will increase application weightage or decrease.
Note: I'm applying to German universities.